# Unable to deploy SSIS package to remote sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am a newbie to SSIS.

I have created Azure VM and installed SQL Server. I need to deploy the ssis package from visual studio in my local to SQL server on Azure VM. Using below command I can login to VM SQL server with windows authentication from SSMS in my local.

> runas /netonly /user:domain\user "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
> Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"

Now, I'm trying to deploy package from Visual studio to VM SQL Server, In the deployment wizard it asks for destination server where not able to login to VM sql server using windows authentication, it throws below error:
[image]
And when using SQL server authentication in deployment wizard for destination server it throws below error:
[image]

How can I deploy packages to Azure VM SQL Server from local ?

Comment: Have you provisioned SSIS in Azure?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: No. I'm trying to deploy to SQL Server in Azure VM(Iaas)

Comment: SSIS must be provisioned in Azure before the feature can be used. If you have not done this, that might be the problem. Take a read on the document I linked to :-)

Comment: I'm not using ADF. using VM on azure and sql server is installed in that VM (IaaS). Want to deploy the SSIS packages to that remote sql server(SQL server on VM) where catalog is already created.

Comment: maybe try the cmdline utility dtutil for deploying SSIS packages

Comment: Using SSMS can you connect to integration services on the server? (so that you can verify it's been provisioned and is running?) If you connect to the database engine can you see SSISDB Database? Can you expand the Integration services catalog?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to lauch VS in the same way you are using SSMS?

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\user "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

Eventually you can build your SSIS solution with VS, copy the ispac file to your VM filesystem and thne import the ispac file inside the ssis catalog with the proper wizard.